Proper usage of K-fold cross validation and finalizing model
I am trying to learn about k-fold cross validation. I am using it on Kaggle dataset of brain tumors MRI trying to classify the images. Kaggle provides two directories Training with 5712 images and testing with 1311 images which gives total of 7023 images. I made accordingly train data frame and test data frame and now my question is, when I perform k-fold cross validation with 5 folds in my case should I use only whole training directory (5712 images) for this k-fold cross-validation not touching test directory, or should I do k-fold cross-validation using whole dataset (7023 images)?
Then another question is at end when I pick model architecture which did best on k-fold cross-validation on average and I want to "finalize" the model as far as I understand I should train now on whole set of training directory (5712) normally and use the test directory (1311 images) for final model evaluation and based on this evaluation report accuracy and loss? Thank you for help and clearing my confusion/misunderstandings.

Yes, when you do cross validation, you should not include the test data in this procedure. The test data is for your evaluation and reporting loss, accuracy, etc. computed on this set makes most sense.

Thank you for clarification, some of the images and sources on internet seemed to suggest doing k-fold validation on the whole dataset, and they didn't clarify that they meant by it only training part of the dataset. So the correct approach is:


Do k-fold cross validation on your training part of the dataset, where it will automatically split it into training part and validation part for each fold.


If results are good for us, we finalize the model by now training normally on all images in training set and then evaluate on test set



That makes most sense to me. Saying that this is 'the correct approach', which applies in all situations is probably not warranted.
